# parse deep json objects mixed with arrays in Java quickly

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am wondering if it's quick to just interpret some JSON into a Java array quickly like so, or if it is better to be use something like Jackson etc.?

Let's say I am parsing a JSON object like this:

```
{ "item1": "item",
  "roles": [ 
        { "roleName": "NormalUser" }
           ],
  "type": "worker"
}
```

And then I have some Java code here (response variable = ResponseEntity from RestTemplate):

```
    logger.info("parsing role...");
    HashMap<String, Object> jsonBody = response.getBody();

    if(jsonBody.containsKey("roles")){          
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> roles = (List<HashMap<String, Object>>)jsonBody.get("roles");

        logger.info("Cast Hashmap, now interpreting...");
        for (HashMap<String, Object> role : roles) {
            logger.info("Found role: " + role.toString());
            String assignedRole = "";
            if(role.containsKey("role")){
                assignedRole = (String) role.get("roleName");
            };
            this.roleAssignments.add(assignedRole);

            logger.info("Assigning role: {}", assignedRole);
        }
    }
```

Comment: gson or jackson is better than parsing

Comment: Entity entity = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Entity.class);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath)

For example

```
String content="some json";
List<String> assignedRoles = JsonPath.read(content, "$.roles[*].roleName");
this.roleAssignments.addAll(assignedRoles);
```

Comment: This is the best library I've seen in Java for parsing JSON. Incredible...